# Arcanum replay value

Tags: arcanum-of-steamworks-and-magick

I finally got around to beating Arcanum: Of Steamworks and Magick Obscura, and I'm curious if I will enjoy a replay.

So my question is, what can change from playthrough to playthrough, other than different combat due to a different character build and different party members?

Comment: Did you play game fully patched? I know there were some bugs around certain quests and certain schematics, but I think the community patches sorted those out?

Comment: I forgot about the patches.

Comment: Did you ever construct the spider mech? I thought that was one of the bugs.

Comment: I made the spider mech. I don't recall it being bugged. I think the medical spider mech was bugged.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd say absolutely. Play it as a magic user, then play it as a technologist. You can also do elf/dwarf/human but in those cases the differences are more cosmetic. It's also fun to try out different specializations: the masters for the highest levels all have different quests.

There are also tons of side quests. It's unlikely that you saw them all in a single playthrough. Different party members? Lots of stuff.

Comment: I played through as a lawful technologist. If I do decide to replay, I'd do an evil magic user. Would there be much change in the story?

Comment: @Arkive No doubt

Answer (score 5):

I'd say you could play this game at least 3 or 4 times. Even if you stick with science, you never have enough points to max out more than a couple of the disciplines. Try it once with chemistry and medicine, and then again with firearms and explosives. Same for magic.

What I find really changes the nature of how you play the game is whether you have skills that allow you to attack from a distance, like firearms and explosives, or skills that work better face to face. This will affect your role in the party and you support the other characters. World of Warcraft simplifies this a bit with the Tank/Damage/Healer setup, but in arcanum it's a little more fuzzy. People can still take on these roles, but its not officially designated.

Personally I just like making grenades and hucking them at people :)